# Problems adding Background Image when creating theme for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am presently following this guide: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ThemeCreationGuide
to create a theme for Google Chrome.

Everything seems to work fine, the only problem i have is applying a background image to the browser. The "theme_ntp_background" that supposed to point and load the background-image seems not to be working :(

Any ideas on what may be wrong? it is definitely not the file path, i ensured this was correct.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Chrome can only load png images in themes, so make sure that the image you're trying to use is a png file.

It would also help if you posted the code found in the manifest file for this theme.